# Firefox Private Mode on Android: Start via ADB - Commandline Parameters?

Tags: android, firefox, adb

I want to start Firefox in "private" mode on Android via the Android Debugging Tools.

```
adb shell am start -a android.activity.MAIN -n org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp -d http://mozilla.org/ --es args "-private"
```

This starts Firefox, but not in private mode. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the mobile Gecko [source code](https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/mobile/android/base/java/org/mozilla/gecko/Tabs.java#58) it takes the *boolean* `private_tab` *extra*. So try

```
adb shell am start -a android.activity.MAIN -n org.mozilla.firefox/org.mozilla.gecko.BrowserApp -d http://mozilla.org/ --ez private_tab true
```

Comment: How did you find this parameter. I spent hours searching the sourcecode.

Comment: just used the built-in Mozilla DXR search tool to check all the extras the main activity takes. it took me like 5 min. you are welcome